# unlink function not working with the relative path

Tags: node.js, express, file-handling

I have a website backend in which I am using express framework and there is a express public folder in which if a user uploads image it get stored inside a upload folder in public.
Then there is another folder outside public folder called routes in which I am creating a path in which i want to delete a certain image inside uploads in public folder.

I am using node js `unlinkSync` function of 'fs' module to do so but when I am specifying the relative path it does not work:
relative path: `../public/uploads/image.jpg`

but
this seems to work : `public/uploads/image.jpg`

can anyone explain me how this works?

folder structure:
`root>public>uploads>image.jpg`
`root>routes>Imagedelete.js`

[This error occurs when i use relative path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u2Sy.png)

Comment: '../public/uploads/image.jpg' and 'public/uploads/image.jpg' are two **different** locations. The first one is *one directory up*, the other isn't. There is no reason for both to work the same unless you somehow have the exact same directory structure mirrored in a subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the working but somehow the unlinkSync function is accepting the path from root directory.

So this works in my case--->
./public/uploads/image.jpg

And also if I am using the absolute path its also working using the 'path' module in node js:

[image]

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you